# Safari flexbox behavior different, makes elements sticky?

Tags: css, safari, flexbox

I am seeing a bizarre bug on Safari (works fine on Chrome and Firefox) where my navigation header which is set to `position:absolute;` is behaving as if it is `position:fixed;`.

No inline-styles are added, no classes change, no CSS is overriding anything. As far as I can tell it's a difference in flex-box implementation? Perhaps because I have nested flex containers?

What is going on here? Open the Codepen below in Chrome and Safari to see the difference.

http://codepen.io/mattaningram/pen/zqmyxZ

Comment: you should write your css comment properly :`/*COMMENT OUT HEIGHT 100% HERE TO GET IT TO WORK IN SAFARI*/` and not `//comment ...`

Comment: Thanks @GCyrillus fixing it now! I think I've been away from non-JS generated CSS for too long.

Answer (score 0):

Welp, figured it out 5 minutes after posting the question.

Apparently Safari does not like the child of a flex-container to have a percentage based height. I simply removed the unnecessary `height:100%;` on the `.stuff-wrap` element and it fixes it in Safari.

Hope this helps people coming across the same issue!